# Laravel mongodb ->getPdo() return null

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I'm using `DB::connection('mongodb')->getPdo()` to check if the database is connected (if not phpunit will mark some test as skipped) and it's turning out that `->getPdo()` always return null. The connection is working proven by that I can use `php artisan migrate` to create new collection and I can insert data into the collection.

Environment :

OS : windows 10 running MAMP 3.2.0

laravel : 5.2.37

jenssegers/mongodb : 3.0.2

Edit 1: Add returned object from using `DB::connection('mongodb')->getMongoDB()->connected`

```
MongoDB\Collection {#647
 +collectionName: "connected",
 +databaseName: "destinycore",
 +manager: MongoDB\Driver\Manager {#640},
 +readConcern: MongoDB\Driver\ReadConcern {#642},
 +readPreference: MongoDB\Driver\ReadPreference {#643},
 +typeMap: [
   "array" => "MongoDB\Model\BSONArray",
   "document" => "MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument",
   "root" => "MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument",
 ],
 +writeConcern: MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern {#644},
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While confusing, it's actually correct. This connection class extends from the base class provided by Laravel. It doesn't return a PDO instance because this is a MongoDB connection. It doesn't actually use PDO, which is only used for SQL-related databases. If you're looking for the "raw" connection for this package, you should use the `getMongoDB` method, which returns a `MongoDB\Client` instance.

Comment: Anyway the thing I want is to verify if a connection to database have been established. Because this is a helper method in my integration test. Basically, if the connection can't be establish phpunit will skip the test.
Is there any method to help me with that?

Comment: You should be able to see if the ->getMongoDB()->connected property is true. It's public.

Comment: @theminer3746 If this fixes it, can you mark my answer as correct?

Comment: I've tried using `DB::connection('mongodb')->getMongoDB()->connected` but, whether mongodb is up or down in my machine, it'll always return `MongoDB\Collection` object (Show in edit 1)

Comment: @theminer3746 can't you just use the connection is something trivial and see if it fails? I presume it's not the 80% use-case, but more like an edge case. You seem to be using a dated version of the MongoDB PHP extension anyway. Also that ->connected boolean was even a deprecated property. With the new extension the connections are lazy, so you'll have to perform an operation in order to determine if the credentials are correct.

Comment: Ok, it's working now.
Now I'm trying to get some data from the database to determine if the database connection could be established

Thank you @Frank de Jonge